# Virtual fields have dynamic model name

Tags: cakephp, model, relational-database

I have a pretty basic virtual field in model `Person`:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    "name" => "CONCAT(Person.first_name, ' ', Person.last_name)"
);
```

And in another model `Cars`, I'm triple referencing `People`, using aliases:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    "Creator" => array(
        "className" => "Person",
        "foreignKey" => "created_by"
    ),
    "Modifier" => array(
        "className" => "Person",
        "foreignKey" => "modified_by"
    ),
    "Person"
);
```

With just `Person` in the `$belongsTo` relation it works fine. However, with an alias, the virtual field is blowing up:

```
Unknown column 'Person.name' in 'where clause'
```

I've tried using `$name` as the model name as suggested [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#name). This gives me a php syntax error.

There must be a way to overcome this, it seems so straightforward. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to declare the model's $virtualFields property somewhere else, so you can do some operations on it.  For example in the model's constructor:

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
     $this->virtualFields = array('name' => 'CONCAT(' . $this->alias . '.first_name, " ", ' . $this->alias . '.last_name)' );

     parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know how it turns out. Seems kind of obvious now seeing it.

Comment: I have found that I need to call ```parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);``` before setting ```$this->virtualFields``` as the parent constructor sets the value of ```$this->alias```...

Answer (score 0):

Removing the model name works:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    "name" => "CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)"
);
```

However, that would blow up if there were more than one model being referenced with one of those field names. I'm putting this here as an answer because it does technically work for my situation at the moment, but I'd like a better answer, or discussion if this answer is the only way to make it work currently.